# Cannot get async javascript to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, railway.js

I'm using node.js, RailwayJS and JugglingDB.

I have a model:

```
Model.afterInitialize = function() {
  var me = this;
  Sequence.getSequence('forModel', function(sequence) {
    me.serialId = sequence;
  });
  me.title = 'Hello';
}
```

Once it's all done only the attribute `title` is set. This isn't surprising but I cannot get it to work. I tried using the `async` module with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.afterInitialize` is part of an third-party API that I cannot change, so **unfortunately there is no way to do this**. I was hoping some sort of infinite loop checking for a flag would work but it doesn't and it would be a bodge even if it did work.

I ended up hooking into another method `Model.beforeSave = function(callback) {};`, which requires a callback.

FYI I was using https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb

Answer (score 2):

added a callback parameter to be able to chain.

```
Model.afterInitialize = function(then)
{
  then = then || function(me) { };

  var me = this;

  Sequence.getSequence('forModel', function(sequence)
  {
    me.serialId = sequence;
    me.title = 'Hello';

    then.call(null, me);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Sequence.getSequence` is asynchronous, the `serialId` will be set from within the callback, *when* it is invoked. Since it's asynchronous, that's probably *after* `Model.afterInitialize` returns. If you have to perform operations that depend on the `serialId` being set, fire them from the `Sequence.getSequence` callback.